Split dataframe according to sub-lists by cutoff value
I want to split the dataframe according to the sublists that given from diving a list into parts where the only value above a cutoff is the first.
e.g. Cutoff = 3
[4,2,3,5,2,1,6,7] => [4,2,3], [5,2,1], [6], [7]
I still need to keep track of the other fields in the dataframe.
I should get the given result from this df
data = {
    "uid": ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"],
    "time_deltas": [
        [4,2, 3],
        [1,1, 4, 8, 3],
        [1,1, 7, 3, 2],
    ],
    "other_field": [["x", "y", "z"], ["x", "y", "z", "x", "y"], ["x", "y", "z", "x", "y"]]
}

df = pl.DataFrame(data)
cutoff = 3

# Split the time_delta column into lists where the maximum time_delta (excluding the first value) is greater than the cutoff. Ensure that the other_field column is also split accordingly.

# Expected Output
# +--------+----------------------+----------------------+
# | uid    | time_deltas          | other_field          |
# | ---    | ---                  | ---                  |
# | str    | list[duration[ms]]   | list[str]            |
# +--------+----------------------+----------------------+
# | Alice  | [4, 2, 3]            | ["x", "y", "z"]      |
# | Bob    | [1, 1]               | ["x", "y"]           |
# | Bob    | [4]                  | ["z"]                |
# | Bob    | [8, 3]               | ["x", "y"]           |
# | Charlie| [1, 1]               | ["x", "y"]           |
# | Charlie| [7,3,2]              | ["z", "x", "y"]      |


If you explode/flatten the lists, you can use .cum_sum() of the comparison .over() each "group" to assign a group id/index to identify each sublist.
(df.explode("time_deltas", "other_field")
   .with_columns(bool = pl.col("time_deltas") > cutoff)
   .with_columns(index = pl.col("bool").cum_sum().over("uid"))
)

shape: (13, 5)
┌─────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬───────┬───────┐
│ uid     ┆ time_deltas ┆ other_field ┆ bool  ┆ index │
│ ---     ┆ ---         ┆ ---         ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str     ┆ i64         ┆ str         ┆ bool  ┆ u32   │
╞═════════╪═════════════╪═════════════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ Alice   ┆ 4           ┆ x           ┆ true  ┆ 1     │
│ Alice   ┆ 2           ┆ y           ┆ false ┆ 1     │
│ Alice   ┆ 3           ┆ z           ┆ false ┆ 1     │
│ Bob     ┆ 1           ┆ x           ┆ false ┆ 0     │
│ Bob     ┆ 1           ┆ y           ┆ false ┆ 0     │
│ Bob     ┆ 4           ┆ z           ┆ true  ┆ 1     │
│ Bob     ┆ 8           ┆ x           ┆ true  ┆ 2     │
│ Bob     ┆ 3           ┆ y           ┆ false ┆ 2     │
│ Charlie ┆ 1           ┆ x           ┆ false ┆ 0     │
│ Charlie ┆ 1           ┆ y           ┆ false ┆ 0     │
│ Charlie ┆ 7           ┆ z           ┆ true  ┆ 1     │
│ Charlie ┆ 3           ┆ x           ┆ false ┆ 1     │
│ Charlie ┆ 2           ┆ y           ┆ false ┆ 1     │
└─────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴───────┴───────┘

If uid is not unique, you could .with_row_index() first before exploding and use that in the .over()
You can then use .group_by() to reassmble the lists.
(df.explode("time_deltas", "other_field")
   .with_columns(index = (pl.col("time_deltas") > cutoff).cum_sum().over("uid"))
   .group_by("index", "uid", maintain_order=True)
   .all()
)

shape: (6, 4)
┌───────┬─────────┬─────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ index ┆ uid     ┆ time_deltas ┆ other_field     │
│ ---   ┆ ---     ┆ ---         ┆ ---             │
│ u32   ┆ str     ┆ list[i64]   ┆ list[str]       │
╞═══════╪═════════╪═════════════╪═════════════════╡
│ 1     ┆ Alice   ┆ [4, 2, 3]   ┆ ["x", "y", "z"] │
│ 0     ┆ Bob     ┆ [1, 1]      ┆ ["x", "y"]      │
│ 1     ┆ Bob     ┆ [4]         ┆ ["z"]           │
│ 2     ┆ Bob     ┆ [8, 3]      ┆ ["x", "y"]      │
│ 0     ┆ Charlie ┆ [1, 1]      ┆ ["x", "y"]      │
│ 1     ┆ Charlie ┆ [7, 3, 2]   ┆ ["z", "x", "y"] │
└───────┴─────────┴─────────────┴─────────────────┘


Similar to @mohammedfaruk 's answer, this is what I considered - I'm posting it because I prefer the split_values and brevity.
import polars as pl

data = {
    "uid": ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"],
    "time_deltas": [
        [4, 2, 3],
        [1, 1, 4, 8, 3],
        [1, 1, 7, 3, 2],
    ],
    "other_field": [["x", "y", "z"], ["x", "y", "z", "x", "y"], ["x", "y", "z", "x", "y"]]
}

df = pl.DataFrame(data)

cutoff = 3


def split_values(values, threshold):
    # indices in values where a value exceeds the threshold (plus start and end indices)
    indices = [i for i, v in enumerate(values) if v > threshold]
    if not indices or indices[0] != 0:
        indices = [0] + indices
    if indices[-1] != len(values):
        indices = indices + [len(values)]

    # return a slice of the values for each pair of indices
    return [values[a:b] for a, b in zip(indices, indices[1:])]


result = (
    df.with_columns(
        pl.col("time_deltas").map_elements(
            # lambda to pass threshold dynamically in map_elements
            lambda values: split_values(values, cutoff),
            return_dtype=pl.List(pl.List(pl.Int64))
        ).alias("time_deltas")
    )
    .explode("time_deltas")
)

print(result)


you can use a function to split time_deltas and other_field based on the specified cutoff value. spliting the time_delas list whenever first value in a sublist exceeds the cutoff and ensuring that the associated other_field elements match these splits
for example:
import pandas as pd

# Your data
data = {
    "uid": ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"],
    "time_deltas": [[4, 2, 3], [1, 1, 4, 8, 3], [1, 1, 7, 3, 2]],
    "other_field": [["x", "y", "z"], ["x", "y", "z", "x", "y"], ["x", "y", "z", "x", "y"]],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
cutoff = 3

# functio
def split_by_cutoff(uid, time_deltas, other_field, cutoff):
    result = []
    temp_time = []
    temp_other = []

    for i, (t, o) in enumerate(zip(time_deltas, other_field)):
        if i == 0 or t > cutoff:
            if temp_time:  
                result.append({"uid": uid, "time_deltas": temp_time, "other_field": temp_other})
            temp_time = [t]  
            temp_other = [o]
        else:
            temp_time.append(t)  
            temp_other.append(o)

    if temp_time:
        result.append({"uid": uid, "time_deltas": temp_time, "other_field": temp_other})
    return result

split_rows = []
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    split_rows.extend(split_by_cutoff(row['uid'], row['time_deltas'], row['other_field'], cutoff))

split_df = pd.DataFrame(split_rows)
print(split_df)

Hope this helps

You can try the code below
import pandas as pd
from numpy import cumsum

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
cutoff = 3

df.explode(["time_deltas", "other_field"]).groupby("uid").apply(
    lambda x: x.assign(grp=cumsum(x["time_deltas"] > cutoff)), include_groups=False
).groupby(["uid", "grp"]).agg(list).reset_index().drop("grp", axis=1)

which gives
       uid time_deltas other_field
0    Alice   [4, 2, 3]   [x, y, z]
1      Bob      [1, 1]      [x, y]
2      Bob         [4]         [z]
3      Bob      [8, 3]      [x, y]
4  Charlie      [1, 1]      [x, y]
5  Charlie   [7, 3, 2]   [z, x, y]

